# AmazonClientException: More data read than expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

When I try to add on object to s3 , it gives `AmazonClientException: Data read has a different length than the expected`.

But the problem is expected length shows 32 bits greater than the actual size.

For eg: 5076681 bytes is actual size on disk. But the we get an exception saying expected 5076713.

```
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        //adding metadata content length along with request
        metadata.setContentLength(contentLengthParam);
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest("Bucket", "fileName", in, metadata)
                .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        PutObjectResult result = s3AwsClient.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

The Exception what i get :

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: More data read than expected: dataLength=5076713; expectedLength=5076681; includeSkipped=false; in.getClass()=class com.amazonaws.internal.ReleasableInputStream; markedSupported=false; marked=0; resetSinceLastMarked=false; markCount=0; resetCount=0
com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.checkLength(LengthCheckInputStream.java:156)
com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.read(LengthCheckInputStream.java:110)
com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:72)
com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.MD5DigestCalculatingInputStream.read(MD5DigestCalculatingInputStream.java:98)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
```

Answer (score 0):

That just means that there is more data in your `HttpURLConnection`'s input stream, than the `contentLengthParam`. What you can do is to read all the content from the connection's input stream into a buffer, count its length, and then write that buffer to S3.

Comment: Hi @madhead , Thank you for your suggestion, but i was actually looking for the reason. On further investigation i found that it happens only with files greater than 4mb.

Answer (score 0):

I am (was) facing the same issue with AWS S3 uploads on my Android app. The issue would only happen to some users and I couldn't figure out how to reproduce the problem.  After playing around for a bit I believe I was able to reproduce the issue reliably and fix it...  I noticed I could trigger the error by attempting to upload the file too quickly after taking a photo with the camera.  I believe I have solved the problem by adding a new Handler().postDelayed() (I used 3s) call in which I then upload my photo.  Haven't been able to reproduce the issue since!